# Mass update model values from JSON post in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I can't figure out the proper method to update a model in laravel and then save it into the database.

I'm using Laravel 4. I am posting a json payload to it from EmberJS.

Here is my update code from my RESTful controller:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $data = Input::json()->all();       
    $user = Users::find($id);
    $user->fill($data['user']);
    $user->save();      
    return json_encode(array('user' => $user->toArray()));
}
```

I need it to parse through the JSON payload, update the attributes on the model, and then save those attributes into the database.

Comment: can you please add an example of the json payload

Comment: did you declare the $fillable attribute in the model ? It enables the model to be auto-populated with the mass-assignment mechanism you seem to be trying to use (hence the fill() )

Comment: if not, check this out mate [Laravel 4 Mass Assignment](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Gadoma - Your "$fillable" answer was correct. make it an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credit should go to gadoma for the right answer. I'm putting it here to document what solved my particular issue.

I had not defined what was allowed to be "Mass assigned" in my model by defining the "fillable" attribute on my model.

Like this:

```
protected $fillable = array();
```

That array should contain the names of the attributes on the model that are allowed to be filled by a mass assignment operation, like "fill".

Answer (score 0):

Try typecasting $data['user'] to array.

```
$user->fill((array)$data['user']);
```